# Algorithms for SMS spam detection

Tags: logistic-regression, naive-bayes-classifier, text-classification, k-nn

Which among KNN, Logistic and Naive Bayes would yield best results for SMS spam 
detection? Is there any other efficient approach worth exploring. 
I am planning to make a python application for SMS spam detection.
Any suggestions or resources would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It totally depends on what sort of feature engineering you use. Except for the case of KNN which is useless. Naive Bayes will work well with Bag of Words and TF-IDF while Logistic regression will perform well on all including Word2Vec.

Comment: Could you give me some insight into feature engineering. Any resources. What it seems to me is that you have to decide the features of an SMS. I am not sure if there are any existing data sets like that. Also I am unable to think of any good features apart from the SMS itself or SMS containing a specific word

Comment: are there any existing libraries or github repo which does SMS spam detection?

Comment: Although you are new but try to get your head around this - https://huggingface.co/transformers/custom_datasets.html. This is almost State of the Art for Sequence Classification. OR just google it, look on youtube. you will find tons of tutorails. Upvote if it helped.